# Unique_ptr in a class

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The Human class turned out to be non-copied, since it contains a field of type unique_ptr, for which the copy constructor and the copying assignment operator have been removed. This prevents the compiler from automatically generating a copy constructor and assignment operator for the Human class.
How can I implement a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator in the Human class? A copy of the human must own a copy of the cat, if the original human owned it.

```
struct Cat {
    Cat(const string& name, int age)
        : name_(name)
        , age_(age)  //
    {
    }
    const string& GetName() const noexcept {
        return name_;
    }
    int GetAge() const noexcept {
        return age_;
    }
    ~Cat() {
    }
    void Speak() const {
        cout << "Meow!"s << endl;
    }

private:
    string name_;
    int age_;
};

unique_ptr<Cat> CreateCat(const string& name) {
    return make_unique<Cat>(name, 2);
}

class Human {
public:
    explicit Human(const string& name)
        : name_(name) {
    }
    
    const string& GetName() const noexcept {
        return name_;
    }
    void SetCat(unique_ptr<Cat>&& cat) noexcept {
        cat_ = std::move(cat);
    }
    unique_ptr<Cat> ReleaseCat() noexcept {
        return std::move(cat_);
    }

private:
    string name_;
    unique_ptr<Cat> cat_;
};
```

Comment: do you want it to be the same cat, or a copy? note that with unique ptr it isn't possible that *both the original and the copied sorceress **own** the same cat*. either they **share** a cat (use shared_ptr), or they each have their own **copy** (copy cat on copying sorceress). By the way, you don't have a sorceress in your code yet....

Comment: If you want behavior like this, why are you using a unique_ptr at all?

Comment: @codeling meaning a copy of a human with a copy of a cat)

Comment: Might be better to handle cat as a value: `Cat cat_;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy constructor might look like

```
Human::Human(const Human& rhs) :
    name_(rhs.name_),
    cat_(rhs.cat_ ? std::make_unique<Cat>(*rhs.cat_) : std::nullptr)
{}
```

but getting rid of `std::unique_ptr` and having `Cat` by value (or `std::optional<Cat>`) would be simpler:

```
Human::Human(const Human&) = default;
```

If `Cat` is polymorphic, a `clone` method would be required:

```
Human::Human(const Human& rhs) :
    name_(rhs.name_),
    animal_(rhs.animal_ ? rhs.animal_->clone() : std::nullptr)
{}
```

Comment: @pixelm Your copy-constructor only copies the cat, not the name.